# Cannot scale azure websites past 3 instances?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Azure web sites (standard) has always allowed scaling up to 10 instances per the documentation and the management portal. However, as of yesterday (3/11/14), I can only scale up to 3. I do not see any announcements regarding this change. Is this a bug in the portal or did something change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue, but it has been mitigated.